# how to make twitter bootstrap expand past the 1170px?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with span13 (can we do that?...it seems to look better)

My more important question is the page only scales to around 1200 even though the twitter bootstrap page says

> With the responsive CSS file added, the grid adapts to be 724px and 1170px wide depending on your viewport

Is there any way to have it adapt up to 2000px?  or am I stuck with 1170px as my maximum size?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work out the size you want including column sizes and margins and then use the Bootstrap customise page to create new css files to work from:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

I'd advise sticking to 12 columns as that's how Bootstrap is set up to work.

Comment: is there bugs in the fluid layout nested then nested again stuff.... http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/2958/  notice how nested works but nested nested is wrong on this page...or at least I can't see what is wrong in my html...everything adds up to 12.

Comment: Have a read up on the grid system: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem In normal (fixed) Bootstrap grids when you nest spans the total must add up to the total of its parent. So if you nest with a span6 div you could have a span2 and a span4 within it. But in the fluid-rows if you nest within a span6 the nested divs must add up to 12.

Comment: Also in your fiddle your adding an inline-style of a border right 1px to a span2 - this will mess up your layout as you're adding an extra pixel width to something that shouldn't be added to. In general you shouldn't style the Bootstrap spanX elements themselves. Add divs within them and style those.

Comment: ouch, thanks...I Thought the purpose of making it so easy to change row to row-fluid was not having to change spans....ick...but ok, all is working much better now!!! thanks!!  I missed that point in the docs and had to re-read it.